# Generate DataGridView column from string

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to create a `DataGridViewColumn` dynamically based on a string value. For example, when setting the `DataGridViewColumn` I am using the code below:

```
 DataGridViewTextBoxColumn col1= new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
 col1.Name = "LineID";
 dgv.Columns.Add(col1);
```

Now, I want to create it dynamically like get the Value in the database. then create the column based on that value:

```
string strColumnType = "DataGridViewTextBoxColumn"
string strColumnName = "Col1"
```

create the column like this:

```
strColumnType strColumnName = new strColumnType();
```

Is this possible? how?

Comment: Yes it is possible. How it is possible is described in the documentation.

Comment: You can always use `switch/case` to check value and create different column. There are also other solutions, e.g. [Activator.CreateInstance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

As @Sinatr comment, you can return the desired column type for each string with a `switch` statement. create a function wich return the match type:

```
DataGridViewColumn GetColumn(string type)
{
    switch (type)
    {
        case "DataGridViewTextBoxColumn":
            return new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        case "DataGridViewComboBoxColumn":
            return new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        //case XYZ: return XYZ
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

then you can write:

```
DataGridViewColumn col1 = GetColumn(strColumnType);
```